# Game keeps playing - Would like it to stop when player wins

Tags: javascript, html

Have added if(gamePlaying) to the event listeners to ensure that the scores only add up when functions running.

If there's a winner the score should stop adding up.

I have set gamePlaying variable to true
Have declared the variable
Have set if statements to all the methods

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,300,600" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
            <link href="http://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
            <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

            <title>Pig Game</title>
        </head>

        <body>
            <div class="wrapper clearfix">
                <div class="player-0-panel active">
                    <div class="player-name" id="name-0">Player 1</div>
                    <div class="player-score" id="score-0">43</div>
                    <div class="player-current-box">
                        <div class="player-current-label">Current</div>
                        <div class="player-current-score" id="current-0">11</div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="player-1-panel">
                    <div class="player-name" id="name-1">Player 2</div>
                    <div class="player-score" id="score-1">72</div>
                    <div class="player-current-box">
                        <div class="player-current-label">Current</div>
                        <div class="player-current-score" id="current-1">0</div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <button class="btn-new"><i class="ion-ios-plus-outline"></i>New game</button>
                <button class="btn-roll"><i class="ion-ios-loop"></i>Roll dice</button>
                <button class="btn-hold"><i class="ion-ios-download-outline"></i>Hold</button>

                <img src="dice-5.png" alt="Dice" class="dice">
            </div>

            <script src="app.js"></script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

JS

```
var scores, roundScore,activePlayer,gamePlaying;

init();  

document.querySelector('.btn-roll').addEventListener('click',function() {

  if(gamePlaying){

    var dice = Math.floor(Math.random()*6 + 1);
    var diceDOM =   document.querySelector('.dice');
    diceDOM.style.display = 'block';
    diceDOM.src = 'dice-' + dice + '.png';

  if (dice !== 1){
    roundScore += dice;
    document.querySelector('#current-'+ activePlayer).textContent = roundScore;
  } else {
    nextPlayer();
   } 
 }
});

document.querySelector('.btn-hold').addEventListener('click',function() {

if(gamePlaying){

scores[activePlayer]+= roundScore;

document.querySelector('#score-' + activePlayer).textContent = scores[activePlayer];

if (scores[activePlayer] >= 20){
  document.querySelector('#name-' + activePlayer).textContent = 'Winner!';
  document.querySelector('.dice').style.display = 'none';
  document.querySelector('.player-' + activePlayer + 'panel').classList.add('winner');
  document.querySelector('.player-' + activePlayer + 'panel').classList.remove('winner');
  gamePlaying = false;
}else{
nextPlayer();
}

    }

});
function nextPlayer() {

  activePlayer === 0 ? activePlayer = 1 : activePlayer = 0;
  roundScore = 0;

  document.getElementById('current-0').textContent = '0';
  document.getElementById('current-1').textContent = '0';
  document.querySelector('.player-0-panel').classList.toggle('active');
  document.querySelector('.player-1-panel').classList.toggle('active');

  document.querySelector('.dice').style.display = 'none';
}

document.querySelector('.btn-new').addEventListener('click',init);

function init() {

  scores = [0,0];
  roundScore = 0;
  activePlayer = 0;
  gamePlaying = true;

  document.querySelector('.dice').style.display = 'none';

  document.getElementById('score-0').textContent = '0';
  document.getElementById('score-1').textContent = '0';
  document.getElementById('current-0').textContent = '0';
  document.getElementById('current-1').textContent = '0';
  document.getElementById('name-0').textContent = 'Player 1';
  document.getElementById('name-1').textContent = 'Player 2';
  document.querySelector('.player-0-panel').classList.remove('winner');
  document.querySelector('.player-1-panel').classList.remove('winner');
  document.querySelector('.player-0-panel').classList.remove('active');
  document.querySelector('.player-1-panel').classList.remove('active');

  document.querySelector('.player-0-panel').classList.add('active');
}
```

When the player is established as a winner, scores should stop adding up and when clicking roll the dice it shouldn't do anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost had it. All you need to do is add a `-` to a couple lines.

Change

```
  document.querySelector('.player-' + activePlayer + 'panel').classList.add('winner');
  document.querySelector('.player-' + activePlayer + 'panel').classList.remove('winner');
```

to

```
  document.querySelector('.player-' + activePlayer + '-panel').classList.add('winner');
  document.querySelector('.player-' + activePlayer + '-panel').classList.remove('winner');
```

It was failing because `document.querySelector('.player-' + activePlayer + 'panel')` is null so you get an error before you reach `gamePlaying = false;`.